# java image reading libraries

Tags: java, image

I am searching for java libraries which

- are able to load/read many image formats
- don't want installation
- are platform independent
- and are not one of these (ImageIO, JAI, Sanselan)

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Why? What's the problem with ImageIO and JAI for example?

Comment: I use them, but ImageIO can't read a lot of formats and JAI has some problems especially with tiff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe use [ImageJ](http://rsbweb.nih.gov/ij/features.html)? At the university we have written plugins for it (a few years ago), but I think you can also use it as a library.